# Xsd2Code using Mono for Android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to read XML->POCO using an xsd, so I use the Xsd2Code generator, giving me a simple Xml Serializer code. When I dry-test this in the regular Windows world, with my XML I have no issues getting around 18 POCOs from the xml-file.

The fun begins in the Android world. I see that the loading of the XML file is done perfect, no issues there I have a perfectly sound XML string. When the Deserialization is complete I only get the first element in the xml file, missing 17 POCOs.

What is wrong here? Is the Xml Serializer/Deserializer working diffrently in Mono?

Comment: You can try testing using Mono on Windows. It might help you narrow the problem down, and might make it easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should find a reduced testcase (simple program) that works on .NET and fails in MonoDroid, and attach it to a new bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Could you please link the bug here?